# Lookahead in Oracle's regular expressions

Tags: regex, oracle, phone-number

I've got a problem with Oracle's regexes. I have lots of phone-numbers in different tables. Now my task is to unify them. So I take out all blanks, underscores, minuses and whatnot. But then the tricky part comes - which seemed so easy at first.

There are numbers both with and without international code, so e.g. 0046812345678 and 0812345678. So I want to replace one single (!) leading zero with '0046'. I thought that `^0(?=[1-9])` would do the job but Oracle seems to think that lookaheads are useless.
`(^0)(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)` doesn't do the job either (or `(^01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09)` for that matter) since it would replace the first non-zero number as well making 0812345678 into 004612345678 (so, the first '8' disappears).

I searched and tried for quite some time now and can't come up with any more possibilities. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know about oracle, but usually you can refer to capturing groups in the replacement string. so for instance, pattern `^0([1-9])` and replacement `0046$1` or `0046\1` or something.

Comment: As another improvement you could try `^0([0-9]{9})$` and replacement as `'0046\1'`

Comment: @shyam that is probably too restrictive... phone number lengths can vary quite a lot.

Comment: @m.buettner Ok. I was simply trying to address the fact that `0` can be part of the rest of the phone number too...hence the length limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the first 1-9 to the result so that only numbers starting with a single `0` are matched. To keep the first 1-9 we capture it (using parenthesis) and add it to the replace part (using `\1`). This seems to work:

```
select regexp_replace('0812345678', '^0([1-9])', '0046\1') from dual;
```

Result:  `0046812345678`

Comment: Tested some different numbers and situations and it seems to work! Thanks a lot both for the reply and for being so fast! :-)